# Activate the LED for a flashlight app

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to make a flashlight app for my iPhone. I have an iPhone 4 and would like to utilize the LED on my iPhone for my project. Can anyone help me to get started with that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the following:

```
AVCaptureSession * session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

[session beginConfiguration];

AVCaptureDevice * device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

if ([device hasTorch] && [device hasFlash]){
[device lockForConfiguration:nil];
[device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
[device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn]; 
[device unlockForConfiguration];

AVCaptureDeviceInput * flashInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:nil];
if (flashInput){
    [session addInput:flashInput];
}
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput * output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [session addOutput:output];
        [output release];
    [session commitConfiguration];  
    [session startRunning];
}
[self setTorchSession:session];
[session release];
```

(From a [discussion](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/51651-access-camera-flash.html) on iPhoneDevSDK)

Comment: Thank you, So I have added a button in the viewcontroller.xib in interfacebuilder. How do I make the button start and stop the flashlight?

Comment: Make an IBOutlet for an IBAction and connect it to the button's selector. Then, in the IBAction, depending on whether the LED is already on, call the code, or call a modified version of the code with all ons replaced with offs.

Comment: Have you checked my other post? I have added a IBOutlet and a IBActon but I don't know how to add my code to the button. Can you have a look and help me out and show me how to add the code to the button.

I know I need to change;

[device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
[device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];

To

[device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
[device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];  

Can you look at my code in the other post and show me how to do this, you can email me holmes2870 @ yahoo.com

I'm new to this so have patience...

Thank you
David H

Answer (score 30):

Here is a shorter version you can now use to turn the LED on or off:

```
- (void)torchOnOff: (BOOL) onOff
{
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ([device hasTorch]) {
        [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
        [device setTorchMode: onOff ? AVCaptureTorchModeOn : AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
}
```

UPDATE: (March 2015)

You can also set the brightness of the torch:

```
- (void)setTorchToLevel:(float)torchLevel
{
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ([device hasTorch]) {
        [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
        if (torchLevel <= 0.0) {
            [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
        }
        else {
            if (torchLevel >= 1.0)
                torchLevel = AVCaptureMaxAvailableTorchLevel;
            BOOL success = [device setTorchModeOnWithLevel:torchLevel   error:nil];
        }
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
}
```

Comment: You only need to have the session running if you are using this code on iOS versions prior to 5.0

Comment: Tested on iOS8! This answer is shorter and easier than the accepted one. @David Holmes should review it...